# Python add cumulative quantity, price to an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, csv

I have trading data in a pandas data frame in this format:

```
price, qty, time
123, 100, 9:00
125, 200, 9:05
130, 300, 9:10
125, 300, 10:01
123, 100, 11:05
```

etc.

I am trying to plot how many shares I bought at what price throughout the day.
The ideas was to get data from my data frame into a new array and plot it.
The array should look like this:

```
123, 200
125, 500
130, 300
```

the time data I can skip for now.
What would be the best way to do this?

```
my_array = []
for item in df:
  if item not in array:
    my_array.append(item[0])
```

that should give me the unique prices I traded at.
How can I now add the cumulative quantities of shares to the array for each price?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: You mean `if item not in my_array:`.

Comment: This will be the answer. https://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=wideeyed&logNo=221439817503&parentCategoryNo=&categoryNo=50&viewDate=&isShowPopularPosts=true&from=search

Comment: Are you willing to use numpy? If so see `np.unique`, [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).